# system of linear equation with additional constraint of minimal variables sum

Tags: algorithm, math, logic, constraints, linear-equation

I have a system of linear equations that I already reduced to a row echelon matrix using Gauss-Jordan elimination. My system with n variables Xn (where Xn is in N0 (=positive integers)) has multiple solutions and I want to find the solution for witch the **Sum of all Xn is minimal**.

How could I do that **programmatically**?

For example consider this system of linear equations:

```
x1 +              + x5 + x6 = 2
     x2           + x5      = 1       
          x3           + x6 = 1
               x4 + x5 + x6 = 1
```

one of the minimal solution I want to obtain is:

```
x3 = x4 = x5 = 0
x1 = x2 = x6 = 1
```

another one would be

```
  x2 = x4 = x6 = 0
  x1 = x3 = x5 = 1
```

But I don't want

```
 x1 = 2
 x2 = x3 = x4 = 1
 x5 = x6 = 0
```

which is also a solution of this system, but not a minimal one according to my criteria as x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 = 5 (whereas it is only 3 for the 2 first solutions)

In case of multiple minimal solutions (like here, where solutions 1 and 2 are both minimal), I don't care about the minimal solution that is returned as long as it is one of the minimal ones

Comment: Are the variable required to be nonnegative? Since there are solutions with different sums, it follows that the achievable sums are not bounded below.

Comment: Yes the variables are non negatives. They belong to the set of positive integers {0,1,2,...}

Comment: So how many variables are there in your instances? How many equations?

Comment: up to a hundred variables with as many equations (but some of these equations might be identical so I may have slightly less equations than variables after the Gauss-Jordan elimination procedure)

Answer (score 1):

Since the variables are all nonnegative, this problem is essentially equivalent to integer programming. Use an off-the-shelf integer program solver and formulate like

```
minimize x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6
subject to
x1                + x5 + x6 = 2
     x2           + x5      = 1
          x3           + x6 = 1
               x4 + x5 + x6 = 1
integers
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6 >= 0
```

(exact syntax depends on the tool).

Comment: Well I don't want to use an external tool. I need to program this solver myself (to integrate it into a game I am programming). That was the goal of my question...

Comment: @ThomasBernard: There are linear programming packages for many languages: you could integrate one into your game. If you really want to program it yourself, search for [simplex method or simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm) and implement it.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Simplex is not enough and Simplex is one of the thoughest programming-tasks there is (if performance is important; and we don't know the size of his instances).

Comment: @ThomasBernard Simplex + depth-first search with best-first backtracking can be done in a few hundred lines, but the performance will be much worse than a well-implemented library. Perhaps your instances will be small enough that it doesn't matter.

Comment: My game is written in Haxe langage and I doubt there is any existing simplex solver library in Haxe... As for my instances, there should be a hundred variables at most.